# Hibernate LEFT JOIN HQL query not counting correctly with condition

Tags: hibernate, hql, left-join, substring

I am using the following HQL:

```
SELECT lo.id, lo.priority, COUNT(p.id) 
FROM LoadingOrder AS lo LEFT OUTER JOIN lo.palettes AS p
WHERE SUBSTRING(p.space.id, 1, 1) = 'B'
```

The problem is it doesn't show me loading orders without palettes. Without the WHERE clause it shows loading orders without paletts (the last column is equal to 0).

I have already tried adding something like this:

```
SELECT lo.id, lo.priority, COUNT(p.id) 
FROM LoadingOrder AS lo LEFT OUTER JOIN lo.palettes AS p
WHERE ((p.id IS NULL) OR (SUBSTRING(p.space.id, 1, 1) = 'B'))
```

but it doesn't help (also when I check if p or p.space.id is null). How to have the condition with substring and also include results where there are no palettes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In straight SQL, suppose you just have the query:
`select * from A left outer join B on A.x=B.x`.  Our results will have at least one row per A, and if there are no B's, we will have null columns on those rows.  Now suppose we add `where B.y=1`.  The DB will first do the outer join, and then it will apply the where clause.  Null values won't be equal to anything, so it will throw out all of those rows.  What you end up will include only A's that have B's, not at all what you are expecting!

The solution in SQL is to add this to the "on" clause, i.e. `select * from A left outer join B on A.x=B.x and B.y=1`.  In this case, the DB will apply this during the outer join, so it will not throw out records.

In Hibernate, it's not as obvious (or well documented), but you should be able to just replace "**where**" in your example with "**with**" and when it translates the HQL into SQL, it should place it in the "on" clause.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Without the knowledge about "with" keyword it was impossible to solve it :/